# How to ignore\escape a parameter passed into a funcion?

Tags: shell

I have the below function :

```
rc_result() {
    rc=$?
    if [ $rc -gt 0 ]; then
      ULTIMO_ERRO=$1
      export log_dir=$2
      export NAME_JOB=$3
      export cluster_logs_dir=$4
      echo $ULTIMO_ERRO
      log_output "$log_dir" "$NAME_JOB" "$cluster_logs_dir"
      exit $rc
    else
      export log_dir=$?
      export NAME_JOB=$?
      export cluster_logs_dir=$?
      log_output "$log_dir" "$NAME_JOB" "$cluster_logs_dir"
    fi
}
```

whenm I'm calling it, I'm passing the below parameters :

```
rc_result "ERROR RUNNING THE SCRIPT" "/data/workdir/sustentacao_id/desenvolvimento/m292121/encaps_logs/logs/" "PP_AAAR_ST_4898_DAVMOV_D_TEST" "/hadoop/cluster_logs/tests/AAAR/aaar-srv-produtos-mov/"
```

NB : the log_output function contains a command :

```
hdfs dfs -copyFromLocal "$log_dir""$NAME_JOB""_""$TIMESTAMP".log $cluster_logs_dir
```

The thing is this, when I have an error, it works fine, but, when I don't have, when the else clause inside my rc_result function is called, it gives me an error because I'm passing the message "ERROR RUNNING THE SCRIPT" as a parameter

So, how could I make the else clause work passing this parameter?

Thats the error when it calls the else clause

```
copyFromLocal: `ERROR RUNNING THE SCRIPT/data/workdir/sustentacao_id/desenvolvimento/m292121/encaps_logs/logs/_20221121_082844.log': No such file or directory
```

Comment: I honestly don't understand your code. `$?` is the status code of the most recent command. In the line `export log_dir=$?`, the last command executed was `[`, and since you took the _else_ branch we know that the status code must be 1. Hence you always set `log_dir` to 1. Furthermore `export NAME_JOB=$?` always sets the variable `NAME_JOB` to 0.

Comment: the idea is that the function rc_result will bring the result of a command, i.e. a spark command, a hql command, etc. so then, my function will check if the rc of the mentioned command was 0 or > 0.
the else part is to treat when there was no error, the $? in my else condition is because I copied one of my tests, I was using number as you can see in the if clause

Comment: Maybe, but each statement overwrites the value of $?. The only place where $? still was the condition of the previous command, is in `rc=$?`. Therefore you should in the_else_ clause also use `$rc` and not `$?`, if you need the value, though I still don't understand why you assigne an exit code to a variable named `log_dir`. Did you every consider running the function with `set -x` turned on?